# Weird function syntax

Tags: javascript

I saw a weird function that looked something like:

```
const x = (a) => (b) => a + b;

console.log(x(1)(2))
```

The output is 3, I understand that it's a function returning a function and both a and b are in the same scope but the questions I have are:

1. How could this be used in real life?
2. What's the advantage of not using a function with 2 parameters and using this instead (for a one-line function)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Comment: It's an example. By itself, for this specific example, this is totally useless and just confusing.

Comment: Check [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185585/what-is-the-advantage-of-currying) out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With this closure, you could get a function with a constant value for later adding.

> 1. How could this be used in real life?

You could take the returned function for a mapping of an array.

> 2. What's the advantage of not using a function with 2 parameters and using this instead (for a one-line function)?

It's a cleaner and functional approach.

```js
const
    x = a => b => a + b,
    add5 = x(5);

console.log([1, 2, 3].map(add5));
```

Comment: Yes, now I see the use of it. I'll look more into currying. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's give that function a better name:

```js
const add = (a) => (b) => a + b
```

Then later you can write

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4] .map (add (5)) //=> [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

which is nicer to read than

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4] .map ((n) => 5 + n) //=> [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This is handy in a chain of `.then()` calls on Promises:

```js
  return fetchList (param)
    .then (map (add (5)))
    .then (filter (lessThan (8)))
    .then (average)
```

(This of course requires curried functions `add`, `lessThan`, `map`, and `filter`, and some simple `average` function.)

Compare this to

```js
  return fetchList (param)
    .then (xs => xs.map (x => add (5, x)))
    .then (xs => xs.filter (x => lessThan (8, x)))
    .then (average)
```

Note that the reason that `average` works the same in both versions of this is that it
takes a single parameter.  One major point of currying is to turn a function into one that takes a single parameter.  It makes a certain style of coding much easier to perform.

Answer (score 2):

Nina gave an excellent answer. I will provide another, a little more advanced example where such closures help a lot with the clarity of the code. Let's combine functions together into a prefix-checker as below and then re-use it as many times as we want:

```js
//given a word, check if a string s starts with this word
const literal = word => s => s && s.startsWith(word);

//allow to combine 2 literals with OR    
const either = (p1, p2) => s => p1(s) || p2(s);

//allow to combine N literals
const any = (...parsers) => parsers.reduce(either);

//create a parser
const check = any(literal('cat'),literal('dog'),literal('cow'));

console.log('cat: ' + check('cat'));
console.log('dog: ' + check('dog is smart'));
console.log('cow: ' + check('cow 123'));
console.log('banana: ' + check('banana'));
```

In reality, it is a simplified parser-combinator (nope, not yet monadic). Extending this approach, you can create parsers for your own programming language, and it would be maintainable and fast.